# How to remove digits from a word, except if the digit stands alone. Using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

THIS is what I have thus far:

```
match = re.sub(r'[0-9]',"","th1s n33ds to be r3m0v3d and this 2 doesnt")
```

This now will remove ALL the numbers throughout the sentence, I tried everything.
Does anyone have an idea around this?

Much appreciated

Comment: `match = re.sub(r'\B[0-9]+\B', "","53l3ct th1s 1 ma63" `The output would be "lct ths ma" Cause now if the digit is at the front of the word, it doesn't want to delete it. THanks for the help! You guys Rock!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\B`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\B[0-9]+\B',"","th1s n33ds to be r3m0v3d and this 2 doesnt")
ths nds to be rmvd and this 2 doesnt
```

Translation from regex into english: remove all digits sequences that are located inside of the word.

> \B - Matches the empty string, but only when it is not at the
>   beginning or end of a word.

EDIT: if digits can start or end the word then this regex will do:

```
>>> re.sub(r'([0-9]+(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])[0-9]+)',"","1th1s n33ds to be r3m0v3d and this 2 doesnt3")
ths nds to be rmvd and this 2 doesnt
```

Translation from regex into english: remove all digits that are followed or preceded by a letter.
This second regex is pretty ugly and I'm sure there is a better way.

Comment: Great yes, thats what I need. What if you have the same sentence with a digit at the beginning and end? as in                               `match = re.sub(r'\B[0-9]+\B', "","53l3ct th1s 1 ma63")`

Answer (score 0):

This works -

```
re.sub(r'(?:[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)|(?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*)',"","th1s n33ds to be r3m0v3d and this 2 doesnt this2")
# output 
'  to be  and this 2 doesnt '
```